# How to update candlestick Highstock chart with new data point

Tags: highcharts, candlestick-chart

I am trying to update my Highstock candlestick chart with new data points but I can not make it work - and I don't know where is the problem. Everything looks good for me, but chart is not updating.

the updatepoint.php gives this as result

```
{"time":"1546978140000", "open":"4112.89677", "high":"4112.9", "low":"4112.8", "close":"4112.9"}
```

when executing the code, the charts updates every minute, but it just clears last candlestick at first update and that's it, no change on next updates

```js
chart: {
  events: {
    load: function() {
      addPopupEvents(this);
      var series = this.series[0];
      setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'http://www.chart.blue/chart/Highstock/updatepoint.php',
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(point) {
            series.addPoint([point.time, point.open, point.high, point.low, point.close], true, true);
          },
        });
      }, 60000);
    }
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert string values to numbers:

```
chart: {
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var series = this.series[0];
            setInterval(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://www.chart.blue/chart/Highstock/updatepoint.php',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(point) {
                        series.addPoint([+point.time, +point.open, +point.high, +point.low, +point.close], true, true);
                    },
                });
            }, 60000);
        }
    }
},
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/suj7zaf2/

Comment: I used Number(point.time) etc but is was still not working, but I figure it out - the problem is that you can not use live update together with partial data loading when updating navigator